# Multimapping and anonymous values

Tags: java

I wish to create an instance of `TreeMap` whose keys will be of type `String` and values of 
type `ArrayList <String>`:

```
Map<String, List<String>> directory = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();  
String[] names = {"Anne","Ben","Charles","Dawn","Edward"};  

for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {  
    directory.put(names[i], new ArrayList<String>());  
}
```

My question here relates to line 5 of the following code. Is it acceptable/best practice to pass an anonymous object (in this case given by new ArrayList()) as the actual argument to the put() method? My rationale for this is that by the nature of a map, these objects can still be reached by the following for example:

```
directory.get("Anne");
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If you wish the Lists inside the Map to be immutbale use Collections.immutableList(new ArrayList<String>()) instead in Line 5 as the second argument to your put().

Comment: oops it should be Collections.unmodifiableList() :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with that. As a matter of fact, I don't even see a reason to call such a thing "anonymous". You are simply avoiding declaring a variable (i.e. a reference to that object - you are still creating the object) that you are never going to use anyway.

There is no such thing as an "anonymous" object in Java. There are anonymous classes, i.e. classes that don't have a name. An object has no concept of a "name". It is simple referred to by one or more references as needed.

Comment: We could say "every object is anonymous" (maybe with exception of enum values), even.

Comment: Thank you MAK. When created does this mean that regardless of whether we provide a reference variable to the values of a map, references to its values are maintained by some mechanism of the map and hence can always be reached by aMap.get(aKey)?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with that at all. I use it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you create a new ArrayList object for every one of those names. Is this what you wanted to do? Whether it is best practice depends on what you are trying to do, it would be best practice to store e.g. the names of the pets these people own (a list of pets for every person).